# Program for student books - Need to insert a copy constructor in it

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to make a program that defines a student class CStudent that stores name information,
Student's faculty number and major to provide:
Create objects using copy constructor
Create objects using an explicit constructor (with parameters)

The problem is , I don't know where exactly to enter the constructor. Here is the code where I got to and how I wrote it.

```
#include <iostream>



using namespace std;
#define max 10
 class CStudent
{
private:
    char name[30];
    int facnum;
    char specialty[20];

public:
    void getDetails(void);
    void putDetails(void);
};

void CStudent::getDetails(void) {
    cout << "enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "enter facnum:";
    cin >> facnum;
    cout << "Enter student speacialty: ";
    cin >> specialty;

}

void CStudent::putDetails(void) {

    cout << " Student details: \n";
    cout << " Name:" << name << " ,facnum: " << facnum << ",Specialty: " << specialty;

}

int main()
{
    CStudent std[max];     
    int n, loop;

    cout << "Enter total number of students: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (loop = 0; loop < n; loop++) {
        cout << "Enter details of student " << loop + 1 << ":\n";
        std[loop].getDetails();
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (loop = 0; loop < n; loop++) {
        cout << "Details of student " << (loop + 1) << ":\n";
        std[loop].putDetails();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `#define` for commonplace things like `max`. That's just doing textual substitution which doesn't care for scope or other context.

Answer (score 0):

A copy constructor works similar to a regular constructor, but the only argument is a reference to another object of the same type. In this case, you should create one in your CSStudent class with the signature:

```cpp
CSStudent(const CSStudent &other);
```

And if you want this to hit on assignment, you will also need to overload the `=` operator in a similar manner:

```cpp
CSStudent& operator=(const CSStudent &other);
```

In these constructors you'll want to copy your data from `other` to `this` and then `return *this` in your operator overload. You can find more information on the C++ website here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Answer (score 0):

usually copy constructor and copy assign operator has below signature.

```
class_name ( const class_name & )
class_name& operator = (const class_name &t)
```

in your case it will became like:

```
CStudent(const CStudent& other)
{
  strcpy (this->name,other->name);
  strcpy (this->specialty,other->specialty);
  this->facnum = other->facnum;
}
```

above code will copy of given CStudent but copy assign operator is like:

```
CStudent s = anotherCStudentObj;
```

copy assign operator in your case much like copy constructor but except that in end of copy assign operator you should add `return *this`.

example:

```
CStudent& operator=(const CStudent& other)
{
  strcpy (this->name,other->name);
  strcpy (this->specialty,other->specialty);
  this->facnum = other->facnum;
  return *this;
}
```

more information about copy constructor [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

more information about copy assign operator [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

Comment: strcpy is not safe, this code WILL write over the stack, if the string is too large to fit

Answer (score 0):

first, please use std::string instead of raw char arrays, it's way easier to store, modify and move the string data around:

```
    #include <string> // include string header
    
    std::string a = "Hello, world!" // explicit std namespace
    
    using namespace std;
    string b = "Hello, world!" // implicit std namespace
```

second, you haven't provided any constructors to the class. Constructor is a special method, named after the class name, which doesn't have a return type:

```
    class CStudent {
    private:
        string name, specialty;
        int facnum;
    public:
        CStudent() = default; // default constructor
                              // with no parameters
        CStudent(string name, int facnum, string specialty) {
            this->name = name;
            this->facnum = facnum;
            this->specialty = specialty;
        } // constructor with specified parameters
        
        // copy constructor is a special constructor,
        // that receives a const class reference as it's parameter:
        CStudent(const CStudent& ref_obj) {
            this->name = ref_obj.name;
            this->facnum = ref_obj.facnum;
            this->specialty = ref_obj.specialty;
        }
    };
```

now you can create objects using these constructors like this:

```
    CStudent a; // default constructed
    
    int facnum;
    string name, specialty; // set the data from console or manually
    CStudent b(name, facnum, specialty);
    CStudent b2 = CStudent(name, facnum, specialty); // the same
    auto b3 = CStudent(name, facnum, specialty); // also the same
    
    CStudent c(b); // copy constructed
    CStudent c2 = b; // the same
```

and usually it's common to have setters/getters for a class field
setter/getter is a method, that gets or sets data from a field:

```
    // set of getters:
    string get_name() const {
        return name;
    }
    
    int get_facnum() const {
        return facnum;
    }
    
    string get_specialty() const {
        return specialty;
    }
    
    // set of setters:
    void set_name(string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    void set_facnum(int facnum) {
        this->facnum = facnum;
    }
    
    void set_specialty(string specialty) {
        this->specialty = specialty;
    }
```

now we can make a function, that will create a CStudent
and set it's data from the console:

```
    static CStudent GetFromConsole() {
        int facnum;
        string name, specialty;
        
        cout << "enter name: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "enter facnum:";
        cin >> facnum;
        cout << "Enter student speacialty: ";
        cin >> specialty;
        
        return CStudent(name, facnum, specialty);
    }
```

and a method, that would print the data to the console:

```
    void PrintStudent() const {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Fac. number: " << facnum << endl;
        cout << "Specialty: " << specialty << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Error (active) E0258 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member 

I did everything as you expained but i get this error ? any solutions?

Comment: so, basically every method is just a plain function with a hidden first parameter: pointer to the object, that called the method. Every time you access a class field, you actually do something like: this->name under the hood. So every method has a hidden parameter this, and static functions don't have them. That's why they are static: they are used outside of object context

Comment: that's why every method is defined inside the class body. If u define a method like this: void empty_method(); then you are actually defining a plain function: void class_name::empty_method(class_name* this);

Comment: every time u call it like this class_name a; a.empty_method(); 
you are actually doing something like this under the hood:
class_name::empty_method(&a);

Comment: and method like this: void method(int a); would actually be
void class_name::method(class_name* this, int a);

Comment: if you still don't get it, write a comment and I'll put a fully working program with comments

Comment: still i'm struggling to fix the error. Everything else is ok. If you have time and desire paste it working so i can see what im doing wrong. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

A working example

```
#include <iostream> // cout/cin
#include <string> // string container
#include <vector> // generic container

using namespace std;

class CStudent {
public:
    // Default constructor
    CStudent() = default;

    // Explicit constructor
    CStudent(string name, int facnum, string specialty) {
        this->name = name;
        this->facnum = facnum;
        this->specialty = specialty;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    CStudent(const CStudent& obj) {
        this->name = obj.name;
        this->facnum = obj.facnum;
        this->specialty = obj.specialty;
    }

    // Method, that prints the contents of the object
    void PrintStudent() const {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Fac. num: " << facnum << endl;
        cout << "Specialty: " << specialty << endl;
    }

private:
    string name;
    int facnum;
    string specialty;
};

// Function, that gets student data from the console
// and creates an instance of the CStudent class using this data
CStudent CreateFromConsole() {
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter fac. num: ";
    int facnum;
    cin >> facnum;

    cout << "Enter specialty: ";
    string specialty;
    cin >> specialty;

    cout << endl;
    return CStudent(name, facnum, specialty); // returns an instance of the class
}

int main() {
    vector<CStudent> students; // stack-like container

    cout << "Enter total number of students: ";
    int count;
    cin >> count;

    cout << "Enter details of students" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // Create an instance of the class
        CStudent student = CreateFromConsole();
        
        // Push a copy of the object into the container
        students.push_back(student);
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Details" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        students[i].PrintStudent();
        cout << endl;
    }

    fflush(stdin); // Reset input console 
    getchar(); // Pause
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is as simple, as possible: there're no any error checking, and there're lots of redundant copies, and global using namespace is actually a bad habit.

Comment: Yes everything worked fine. Didnt have time this week to work on it more but now im trying to add operator for = , == , comparison operator by faculty number. Any recommends and explains how to make it work simple?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, if I'am too late, here's the copy assignment operator and comparison operator example:

```
class CStudent {
//         ...
//    the rest of the class
//         ...
private:
    void swap(CStudent& refObj) {                      // helper method, that would
        std::swap(this->name, refObj.name);            // swap data between two 
        std::swap(this->facnum, refObj.facnum);        // CStudent objects  
        std::swap(this->specialty, refObj.specialty);
    }

public:
    // copy assignment operator
    // allows to copy the data from one object
    // to an existing object
    // usage:
    //  CStudent a, b;
    //  // init a and b
    //  a = b; // a now holds a copy of the b's data 
    CStudent& operator=(const CStudent& refObj) {
        CStudent temp(refObj); // create a temporary copy
        this->swap(temp);      // swap the contents of this object and the copy
        return *this;          // return a reference to this object
                               
                               // after the method execution, the temp object
                               // that contains our old data will be destroyed
                               // this insures safe assignment, even if we assign
                               // the object to itself
    }
    
    // equality comparison operator
    // usage:
    //  CStudent a, b;
    //  // init a and b
    //  if (a == b) // the equality comparison operator is called
    //      cout << "Objects are equal\n";
    //  else
    //      cout << "Objects are not equal\n";
    //
    friend bool operator==(const CStudent& refA, const CStudent& refB) {
        return                                 // checks if
            refA.name == refB.name &&          // the names are equal AND
            refA.facnum == refB.facnum &&      // the fac.nums are equal AND
            refA.specialty == refB.specialty;  // the specialties are equal
    }
    // this is NOT a method, but a free function,
    // that is allowed to access private members and methods of the class
};
```